# Count number of ways that people can ride a chairlift

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I've come across a fun problem that I couldn't generalize.

### Description

3 students arrive at a chairlift. They are free to use up to 3 consecutive chairlifts (no empty chairlifts between them). So they could all go on the same, split themselves and go on 2 or each one goes on its own. An empty chairlift in front of them does not count as separate possibility.

Each chairlift has 3 free seats (or $n$ seats for $n$ students). The students can arrange themselves on the seats freely.

So there are three ways how the students can arrange themselves on the lifts (slashes separate chairlifts): $3, 2/1, 1/2$ or $1/1/1$.

### Questions

How many ways are there that the students ride the chairlift? Denote that number as $D_3$ and for $n$ students $D_n$.

What is $D_4$?

Is there a closed-form expression for $D_n$?

### What I've tried

For $D_3$, I just listed the possibilities and got $276$, which seems to be correct. Also, $D_1=1, D_2=10$.
Here is a picture that lists all possibilities for $D_2$:

[image: Lifts for n=2]

For $D_4$ I've got $14\,712$.

The number of ways that $n$ students can distribute themselves on $n$ chairlifts with $n$ seats can be calculated with the [partition function p](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html), I think. So for 3 students, the possibilities are $\{3\}, \{2,1\}, \{1,1,1\}$. It is relatively easy to continue to perform the combinatorics in each partition. For the first, I got $3!=6$, for the second $3\cdot 2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot3=108$ and for the third $3^3\cdot3!=162$.

But I have trouble to generalize the combinatorical calculations.

Comment: I don't understand your calculations. If you have 3 students, one taking each of three chairlifts, how do you get 162 ways?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I forgot to mention that there are 3 seats on each chairlift. So in addition to chosing the chairlift, the students can chose the seat on each chairlift. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you explain$D_2 = 10$ ?  It seems to me that the two lifts could be filled as $AB|-,\; BA|-,\; A|B\;\;and\;\;B|A$ yielding $3 + 3+(3*3)+(3*3) =24\;\;$ unless I am misinterpreting the question.

Comment: @trueblueanil Thanks for your comment. I've added a picture that lists all possibilities for $D_2$. Does that help?

Comment: The top two configurations in your picture show both students in the same chairlift, but can’t this be in the first or second chairlift? That would give two additional possibilities for a total of $12$. To generalize, Is this right? There are $n^2$ places for each student to sit (seat number $1$ through $n$ of chairlift number $1$ through $n$), so the number of ways this can be done is $n^2$ places for student $1$ to sit, $n^2-1$ places for student $2$, and so on, or $n^2\cdot(n^2-1)\cdots(n^2-n+1)$.

Comment: Oh, I thought each lift has $3$ seats, I see that each is to have $n$ seats. Let me work out $D_3$

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your comment. I thinks it's a good point. But the person who posed the question seemed to take these options as equal. Maybe I shouldn't have written that two chairlifts are available for them, but just that there are at maximum two they can use.

Answer (score 1):

**Working for $D_3$**

I have rechecked  answers, the discrepancy is coming when only one lift is being used. There are **three** ways to choose the lift used, and $3!$ ways to place the persons in that lift $\to 18\;\;$ ways

$18+108+162=288$

However, I am not immediately able to see a simple way to generalize for $n$

---

**Added**

Here's a much simpler way to compute $D_3$

Imagine $3$ boxes with $3$ slots each **arranged in a circle**

If only one box is to be filled, first person can go to any of $9$ slots, but the next two are now restricted to the remaining two slots in that box, so $9\cdot2\cdot1 = 18$

If two boxes are to be filled, put the first person anywhere, and the other two in a **neighbouring** box, so $9\cdot6\cdot2  = 108$

If three boxes are to be filled, $9\cdot6\cdot3 = 162$

This is a much better formulation, and you could try out $D_4$ in this manner, and see if it leads anywhere !

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. My thoughts were as follows: When two seats are used, there are two ways to distribute the students: 2/1, 1/2. Every student has three seats to pick from, so for the case when two are seated: $3\cdot2$ and for the single one: $3$. So: $3\cdot 2\cdot 3$. But there are $3$ possibilities for who rides alone, so multiply that by $3$. Finally, because there are $2$ ways in which $3$ students can be arranged on two lifts, I multiplied that with $2$, ending up with: $3\cdot2\cdot3\cdot 3\cdot2 = 108$. An for all separately: $3^3\cdot 3!=162$.